# How to make copies of an enum without copy pasting code?

Tags: java, enums

I am making enums to assist in reading and handling excel imports of products with components.

I have currently made the following two enums.

```java
    public enum ProductSheetColumns {
        PRODUCT_ID("Product ID", "A"),
        PRODUCT_NAME("Product Name", "B"),
        COST("Cost", "C");

        private String columnName;
        private String columnIndex;

        ProductSheetColumns(String columnName, String columnIndex) {
            this.columnName = columnName;
            this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        }

        public String sheetName() {
            return "Product Sheet";
        }

        public String columnName() {
            return columnName;
        }

        public String columnIndex() {
            return columnIndex;
        }
    }

    public enum ComponentSheetColumns {
        PRODUCT_ID("Product ID","A"),
        COMPONENT_ID("Component ID","B"),
        QUANTITY("Quantity","C");

        private String columnName;
        private String columnIndex;

        ComponentSheetColumns(String columnName, String columnIndex) {
            this.columnName = columnName;
            this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        }

        public String sheetName() {
            return "Component Sheet";
        }

        public String columnName() {
            return columnName;
        }

        public String columnIndex() {
            return columnIndex;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, except for the naming of the constants and enum names, they are largely the same enum.

Is there any way to reduce the code to something like this while keeping the methods?

```java
    public enum ProductSheetColumns {
        PRODUCT_ID("Temporary Product ID", "A"),
        PRODUCT_NAME("Product Name", "B"),
        ADDITIONAL_COST("Additional Cost", "C");
    }

    public enum ComponentSheetColumns {
        PRODUCT_ID("Product ID","A"),
        COMPONENT_ID("Component ID","B"),
        QUANTITY("Quantity","C");
    }
```

I have tried to create an interface but all that does is make me have to add an @Override tag to the enum class. I cannot seem to extend the class or inherit the enum constructor.

EDIT: To clarify the above code sample, the below code does not work but I want to know if it's possible to do something to the same effect with enums:

```java
    public enum ProductSheetColumns extends ExcelSheetColumns {
        PRODUCT_ID("Temporary Product ID", "A"),
        PRODUCT_NAME("Product Name", "B"),
        ADDITIONAL_COST("Additional Cost", "C");

        ProductSheetColumns(String columnName, String columnIndex) {
            super(columnName, columnIndex);
        }

        public String sheetName() {
            return "Product Sheet";
        }
    }

    public enum ComponentSheetColumns extends ExcelSheetColumns {
        PRODUCT_ID("Product ID","A"),
        COMPONENT_ID("Component ID","B"),
        QUANTITY("Quantity","C");

        ProductSheetColumns(String columnName, String columnIndex) {
            super(columnName, columnIndex);
        }

        public String sheetName() {
            return "Component Sheet";
        }
    }


    public enum ExcelSheetColumns {
        ;

        private String columnName;
        private String columnIndex;

        ExcelSheetColumns(String columnName, String columnIndex) {
            this.columnName = columnName;
            this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        }

        public String columnName() {
            return columnName;
        }

        public String columnIndex() {
            return columnIndex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have two distinct enumerations here. That warrants two distinct types. It seems to me that the number of values is rather to be seen as coincidental.

Comment: The amount of enums is coincidental, sure, but the data specified in the constructor (Column name and column index) will be the same for these two and any further enums declared that will be used for parsing excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy-paste is unavoidable.  An `enum` cannot extend another class, and an interface cannot declare state variables.

Alternatively, don't use an `enum` for this.  Declare your own enum-like classes.  You could model them similarly to the singleton pattern; e.g.

```
public abstract class EBase {
   // common state declarations
   // constructor
   // common methods
}

public class E1 extends EBase {
    public static final E1V1 = new E1(...);
    public static final E1V2 = new E1(...);
    ...
    // specific state variables
    // constructor
    // specific methods
}
```

This approach doesn't work for all `enum` use-cases.  For example, you can't use the above instead of an `enum` in a `switch` statement.   If you need *real* `enum` classes, copy and paste is the only solution.